# Can switch statements be inside a Function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a program that inputs a student's average and returns: - A if the student's average is 90-100 
- B if the student's average is 80-89 
- C if the student's average is 70-90 
- D if the student's average is 60-69 
- E if the student's average is 0-59 
- If the average is NOT between 0 and 100, display "invalid input".

First, should ask the user to input the student's average, validate the average (=value should be between 1 -100), and then: - if valid, call a function to determine and return A,B,C,D, or E depending on the average. - If the average is not valid or if the user pressed cancel button, display an alert message and exit the program.

Here is my code so far:

```
var myAvg = prompt("Please enter your grade percentage",0) 

if ( isNaN(myAvg) || myAvg < 1 || myAvg > 100 ) { 
    alert("Average must be a percentage value. Please re-enter your grade again."); 
}

function myAvg (gradeA,gradeB,gradeC,gradeD,gradeE) { 

  switch (true) {

    case (myAvg >= 90 && myAvg < 100):
         document.write("Your grade is an myAvg<br />" );
         document.write(gradeA + " " );
         break;

    case (myAvg >= 80 && myAvg < 89):
         document.write("Your grade is an myAvg<br />" );
         break;

    case (myAvg >= 70 && myAvg < 79):
        document.write("Your grade is an myAvg<br />" );
        break;

    case (myAvg >= 60 && myAvg < 69):
        document.write("Your grade is an myAvg<br />" );
        break;

    case (myAvg >= 0 && myAvg < 59):
        document.write("Your grade is an myAvg<br />" );
        break;

    default: document.write("Please enter a valid percentage<br />");

  }
}

myAvg("gradeA", "B", "C", "D", "E" );
```

Comment: Yes, you can have a switch statement inside of a function.

Comment: That is the wrong way to use a switch statement. Use if/else if

Comment: Yes, a switch block can go inside a function.  You can simplify your cases a bit more though.  For example, case (myAvg >= 90 && myAvg < 100) can be written as case (myAvg >= 90), since you are already checking that it can't be > 100.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code does when fixed up a little:

```
function myAvg (average, gradeA,gradeB,gradeC,gradeD,gradeE) { switch (true) {
   document.write("Your grade is an average<br />" );
   if (average >= 90){
      document.write(gradeA + " " );
   } else if  (average >= 80){
      document.write(gradeB + " " );
   } else if  (average >= 70){
      document.write(gradeC + " " );
   } else if  (average >= 60){
      document.write(gradeD + " " );
   } else {
      document.write(gradeE + " " );
   }
}

var average = prompt("Please enter your grade percentage",0)
if ( isNaN(average) || average < 0 || average > 100 ) { 
  alert("Average must be a percentage value. Please re-enter your grade again."); 
} else {
  myAvg(average, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" );
}
```

You can have a switch statement inside a function, yes, but you're not using it correctly.  In Javascript (unlike Perl, Ruby or maybe Python), you can't put conditions inside of a switch/case like that.  That's a task for if/else if.  Second, since you already established that the average is >= 0 and <= 100, you don't need to check those inside the function.  Third, you don't need to specify the upper range in the script, you can just eliminate the possibilities one by one as above.  Fourth, you have a name conflict with all those "myAvg" words.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `switch` or anything remotely similar (the closest would be a `dict` with values that are functions to call for each case, and that would be more C-like, with direct equality checks, not conditional evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of what you're doing.  I kept it pretty close to what you're doing, but this is how I'd break the parts down.  To make this work, you also need to add a div in the html (I don't love using "document.write"):

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

You can replace that part, if you want, though. There are better ways to do a bunch of these pieces with other libraries, but this should help you along.

```
    function getGrade(score, grades) {
        grades = grades || [
            {
                min: 90,
                grade: 'A'
            },
            {
                min: 80,
                grade: 'B'
            },
            {
                min: 70,
                grade: 'C'
            },
            {
                min: 60,
                grade: 'D'
            },
            {
                min: 0,
                grade: 'F'
            }
       ];
        for (var i in grades.length) {
            if (score >= grades[i].min) return grades[i].grade;
        }
        return;
    }

    function showGrade(score) {
        var grade = getGrade(score);
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Your grade is: " + grade;
    }

    function getScore() {
        var score = prompt("Please enter your grade percentage", 0);
        if (isNaN(score) || score < 0) {
            alert("Average must be a percentage value. Please re-enter your grade percentage.");
            getScore();
        } else {
            showGrade(score);
        }
    }
    getScore();
```

Hope this helps.

--Will

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type= "javascript/text">

function averageGrade(myAvg) 
{   
    if (myAvg >= 90)
    {
        return alert("Your average is an A");   
    }
    else if (myAvg >=80)
    {
        return alert("Your average is an B");
    }
    else if (myAvg >=70)
    {
        return alert("Your average is an C");
    }
    else if (myAvg >=60)
    {
        return alert("Your average is an D");
    }
    else if (myAvg >=0)
    {
        return alert("Your average is an E");
    }
}

var myAvg = prompt("Please enter your average",0);

averageGrade(myAvg)

</script>
```